# #357951 Is this correct approach showing two Divs side by side in vf page?

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" tabStyle="Account" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
    <html >
        
        <head>
            <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}" />
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.lightningDesignSystem}" />
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.GC_Styles}" /> 
            <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.GC_init}" />
            <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.mainjs}" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
<div class="slds-media">
<div class="slds-media__body">
<p class="slds-page-header__title slds-align-middle">
<span> Customer Verification</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    
<apex:form >
<apex:pagemessages />  
    <div class="slds-card__body" style="width: 50%; float:left; height:100px;">
              <apex:outputPanel id="filterControls">
                  <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center">
                      <div class="slds-form-element" style="padding:10px;">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Enter OTP</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Show Name</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                          <label class="slds-form-element__label">Show Name</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                          <label class="slds-form-element__label">Show Name</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body" style="width: 50%; float:left; height:100px;">
              <apex:outputPanel id="filterControls2">
                  <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center" style="padding:10px;">
                      <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Enter OTP</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Show Name</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                          <label class="slds-form-element__label">Show Name</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                          <label class="slds-form-element__label">Show Name</label>
                          <apex:inputText label="Show Name" styleClass="slds-input" style="width: 100%;" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
    
</apex:form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, no. A modern VF page should not do this. The preferred design would be to use the appropriate tags for this:

```
<apex:page doctype="html-5.0">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.GC_Styles}" /> 
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.GC_init}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.mainjs}" />
    <!-- include SLDS -->
    <apex:slds />
    <!-- SLDS scope -->
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <span>Left Side Content</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <span>Right Side Content</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

You can place the additional code you have within those sections as appropriate.